# How to make elements take 100% of their parent's space?

Tags: html, css, layout, height

I have some links that I need to take up 100% of the height available to them, unfortunately I can't get it to work

JSFiddle Version (you can try it out yourself): [JSFiddle With Same Exact Code](https://jsfiddle.net/x2u6dv9w/)

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
}

nav span {
    display: inline-block;
}

nav {
    background-color: #ED2939;
}

nav h1 {
    background-color: blue;
}

nav a {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/styles.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <span>
            <h1>My Page</h1>
        </span>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">More</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see, the links won't take up 100% of the space, despite having `display: inline-block` and `height: 100%`, how can I do this without hard-coding the values or using padding? And after that, center the text vertically?

Comment: make the container a flexbox container

Comment: It is you answering a question of mine yet again (thanks so much), let me try? What will this do - how does it work?

Comment: flexbox has a stretch alignment by default that will make the element take all the height (you need to also remove height:100%)

Comment: Which element should I add this to?

Comment: I tried doing each a tag but it didn't work.

Comment: the parent container (nav element in your case)

Comment: Like Temani said, set nav {display:flex;}

Comment: I did that, but how would align the content vertically, {align-items: center} takes away the stretch? @TemaniAfif

Comment: You can manually set line-height to a elements. In your case 27px will do.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without hard coding? And could one of you please make a nicely formatted answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**THESE ARE THE EDITS TO MAKE TO THE CODE**

```
nav {
    background-color: #ED2939;
    display:flex;
}
nav a {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

**SUMMARY**

Set "nav" and "a" to flex and align center "a" elements.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b9aergwu/

Answer (score 1):

Just for clearance, why your css doesn't work as expected:

Working with percentage `height` is relative the element's parent. If the parent element, in your case `nav` has no height set, the elements height (in your case `nav a`) defaults to *auto*.

So for your example to work, you need to set the height of `nav` to some non-percentage fixed value, for instance *28px*. However, your inline-block elements will have an align issue along with a natural visible space preceeding the element.

As answered above, either stick to *display: flex* - Read through a nice guide here [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or (outdated) `display: block; float: left;` and a set `line-height`.